# Node.JS wrapped in .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, node.js, frameworks

Pardon if it's a dumb question, but I'm trying to build a personal website and, in order to kill two birds with one stone, use the website to fulfill the requirements for a web development class at my university. I want to build my website using Node JS with MongoDB and Bootstrap, but my course requirements at a later project require that I migrate my project (other students are expected to only have designed their website using pure HTML and CSS) into a .NET framework and use Microsoft SQL Server as a database.

I'd like to know whether or not I can wrap or use Node JS inside .NET or if it is feasible for me to fork my personal website to another version utilizing Microsoft technology.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, you could not "wrap" or use in a practical way Node.JS inside of an ASP.NET web site. While you could theoretically start new processes from ASP.NET that run Node.JS code, it would be an unnecessarily complex setup (as you'd need to manage the processes, threads, etc.).

You can certainly use MongoDB and Bootstrap within an ASP.NET application, so some of your work could be shared.

Answer (score 0):

If you will have the ability to configure IIS on your Windows server, you could use nodeiis to host a Node.js alongside a .NET site:

https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode

This approach works well. If you take this approach, be sure that any Node modules you include will work on Windows.